# Suppose that $H$ and $K$ are two subgroups of a group $G$.Assume that $[G:H]=2$ and $K$ is not a subgroup of $H$.Show that $HK=G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

**Suppose that $H$ and $K$ are two subgroups of a group $G$.Assume that $[G:H]=2$ and $K$ is not a subgroup of $H$.Show that $HK=G$.**

Since Index of $H$ in $G$ is $2$ , $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ and $K$ is a subgroup of $G$ hence $HK=KH$ is a subgroup of $G$.Now, how to prove  $HK=G$?

Comment: I have answered that question yesterday.

Comment: $H$ is a subgroup of $HK$.

Comment: If $G$ is a finite group it is easy to prove. Just observe that $H \cap K \lneq K.$ Then $$|HK| = \dfrac {|H||K|} {|H \cap K|} = \dfrac {|G|} {2} [K : (H \cap K)] \geq |G|.$$

Answer (score 4):

Let $x\in K$ not in $H$, and $p:G\rightarrow G/H$ the quotient map, $p(x)$ generates $G/H$, this implies that if $y$ is  any element of $G$ not in $H$,  $p(y)=p(x)$ since the order of $G/H$ is $2$ and $p(y)$ is not the identity, we deduce that $p(x^{-1}y=1$ and $x^{-1}y\in H$